# How make a flex grow div hide its overflow content

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, tailwind-css, overflow

Using tailwinds css. I have a div which takes all available space thanks to flex-grow class. It also has overflow-scroll to hide its content.

Inside this div I have a component with h-full class. The content of this component is a list of cards. I want it to be limited in height by its parent.

But the component is not limited in height by its parent. I have to set a fixed height so the the overflow content is hide and scrollable.

However I do not want to set a fixed height as the list of cards is variable.

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-v13-2-ga3ymh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: please share a stackblitz where the issue happens and what is the expected output on that stackblitz!

Comment: @NarenMurali thanks for your reply, I edited the question : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-v13-2-ga3ymh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you just need to change overflow-scroll into overflow-hidden from div, and go to my-component css file and add :

```css
:host {
flex-grow: 1; // dont forget to make its parent flex, so the component can take its parent height
display: flex;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

:host pseudo-class is used in CSS to target the host element of a component. The host element is the element to which the Angular component is attached in the DOM.

i made an example for you in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-v13-2-hq2gwx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) for more details

**#Edit**

you just need to change subdiv2 dispay into flex that will change the layout behavior of its children, flex items will try to fit into their container without overflowing

here is the new one :
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-v13-2-v66yvs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am not sure it solves the problem. I reproduce tmy simplified structure here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-v13-2-ga3ymh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Ryley38 I've updated my answer, you can check now.